# How to iterate over a list with named values python

Tags: python, list, loops

I want to be able to iterate over a list with named lists inside

I tried doing this:

```
Objects = {

    "Enemies":[

        "Enemy1",

        "Enemy2",

        "Enemy3"

    ],

    "Walls":[

        "Wall1",

        "Wall2",

        "Wall3"

    ]

}

for Type in Objects:

    for Object in Type:

        print(Object)
```

But this doesn't work and prints the letters of the Types under each other

Comment: What do you mean by named lists? You just have a list of strings.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: `Objects` is a dictionary, not a list. You need to learn the difference if you expect to do any Python programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for Type in Objects` loops over the keys of the dictionary. You want to loop over the values.

```
for v in Objects.values():
    for name in v:
        print(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing what you are seeing because Objects is a dictionary.  If Objects were a list of lists, then your loop would work.  If you want it as a dictionary,

```
for tag, object_list in Objects.items():
    for Object in object_list:
        print(Object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following iteration:

```
for Type in Objects:
    for Object in Objects[Type]: 
        print(Object)
```